# Service Fabric Application fails to find the managed identity endpoint

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-managed-identity

The Service Fabric cluster exists, the applications exists and are running. The user-assigned managed identity exists in the same resource group the cluster is. NOTE: I do not know how to verify whether it is assigned to the cluster or not.

Code is trying to create a Storage queues client using the identity and I get the error below, which I think means that the fabric:/System/ManagedIdentityTokenService is not running. NOTE: I do not know how to verify whether the service is running or not.

NOTE: Very similar code worked in other clusters.

NOTE: the underlying VMSS does have the managed identity associated to it.

NOTE: I am using Storage SDK 12.  The C# code does the following:

```
ManagedIdentityCredentials cred = new ManagedIdentityCredentials(ClientId: "XYZ...");
string queueEndpoint = string.Format("https://{0}.queue.core.windows.net/{1}", accountName, queueName);
QueueClient qc = QueueClient(new Uri(queueEndpoint), cred);
bool b = await qc.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();  // This one throws the error below.
```

Any guidance to fix this issue would be appreciated.

Error:
Trying to create a queue (using MSI) failed with exception Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: No managed identity endpoint found.
at Azure.Identity.ExtendedAccessToken.GetTokenOrThrow()
at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Azure.Core.Pipeline.BearerTokenAuthenticationPolicy.AccessTokenCache.d__11.MoveNext()

Comment: Did you configure the managed identity as the [nodepool identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-portal-windows-vmss#user-assigned-managed-identity)?

Comment: Thanks for answer!

Yes, the VMSS has the identity configured.
It is my guess that when the cluster was created the Token service was not enabled, but I did not create the cluster and I do not have access to its configuration.

Comment: as far as I know, you get the token service enabled by assigning a managed identity to a VM(SS)... it would make sense to verify that it is configured correctly somehow.